# Bash, read line by line from file, with IFS

Tags: bash, line

I'm having this code from http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/While_loop, used to read line by line from a file

```
file=/etc/resolv.conf
while IFS= read -r line
do
        # echo line is stored in $line
    echo $line
done < "$file"
```

the part I don't understand is `IFS=` and how it contributes to this functionality. Could anybody explain this to me? Thanks.

Comment: Check [the equivalent question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123/22565) on [unix.SE].

Answer (score -4, accepted):

IFS is a variable for the line separator (or actually "Internal Field Separator"). That code will effectively empty out the line separator for your read command and set it to its default. Sometimes IFS is changed somewhere else in the code due to users wanting other "line" endings, like reading one sentence at a time (`IFS=.`) or similar.

I guess they included the `IFS=` here just to make sure it works or everyone, regardless of the previous value on the IFS variable. The code should still work without `IFS=`

Comment: that's true, without `IFS=` it's still working fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: just one quick thing, we can put such an assignment `IFS=` and `read -r line` in a same line? It's allowed?

Comment: user121870, yes, it's allowed. When putting variables in front of a command he variable will be visible to that command only. This applies to all Bash commands, even those you write in your terminal yourself. Try for example this command: "MANWIDTH=20 man bash".

Comment: Setting `IFS` to a null does not set it to its default (which is space, tab, newline). It's not for line endings only, it's used to do word splitting. To read one sentence at a time, you would use the `-d` delimiter option with `read`.

Comment: This answer is incorrect -- `IFS` is set to the empty string to prevent `read` from stripping leading and trailing whitespace from each line.

Comment: IFS is not a line separator, it's a **field** separator. That means it's used to separate both lines and within lines. But in this case, since you're using `read` with a single output variable, it works. For example, if you want to parse /etc/resolv.conf quicker, you can use `while IFS=' ' read -r name address` to split the fields in the same operation.

Answer (score 45):

In this case, `IFS` is set to the empty string to prevent `read` from stripping leading and trailing whitespace from the line.

Changing `IFS` is usually done to control how the input will be split into multiple fields.  But in this case, because there's only one variable name given to `read`, `read` won't ever split the input into multiple fields regardless of the value of `IFS`.  It will, however, remove the leading and trailing whitespace as mandated in the POSIX specification (assuming the value of `IFS` contains whitespace or is unset).

See the POSIX specification for [read](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) and [field splitting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05) for details about how it works.

Answer (score 4):

In the third example on that page, setting `IFS` to null prevents word splitting which makes that code not work. Here is that code:

```
while IFS= read -r field1 field2 field3 ... fieldN
do
    command1 on $field1
    command2 on $field1 and $field3
    ..
    ....
    commandN on $field1 ... $fieldN
done < "/path/to dir/file name with space"
```

As written, all the words on the line are stored in `field1` and `field2`, etc., are empty. Change the line to this and it will work properly:

```
while read -r field1 field2 field3 ... fieldN
```

Answer (score -3):

To make `IFS` a genuine line separator, use `IFS=$'\012'`.

Comment: You didn't answer the question. The question was to explain the part `IFS=` in the command, and explain its use. And by the way, `IFS=$'\n'` would be (arguably) less cryptic.

Comment: Quite true.  But that part has essentially been answered above, and these are the gory details.  Perhaps this questions should be considered answered.

Comment: If the question has already been answered, then there's no point in adding answers that don't answer the question. Oh well, it's your choice; maybe you'll even get upvotes for that. Or not. Wait and see.