# How do I retrieve the header when I want to look at grep output of something in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

Let's suppose I pipe the output of a command and want to filter lines with grep but also keep the first one which is a header. I saw someone type something akin to this:

```
the command | (read l; echo$l) | grep bla | less
```

and it extracted the first line (header), then grepped the rest of the file for the lines matching bla and the output of that went to `less` for inspection. Of course the above command doesn't work but that's the idea, what part of it is wrong?

Answer (score 6):

With awk:

```
command | awk 'NR==1||/bla/'
```

Thanks to @doubleDown for pointing out that `{print}` is unnecessary since it is the default action.

With perl:

```
command | perl -ne 'print if $.==1 or /bla/'
```

(If you need perl irregular expressions, perl is probably available :) )

Comment: You don't need the `{print}` as it is the default action.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it doesn't satisfy the asker's "with grep" requirement.  Without `grep`, you can't pass useful `grep` command-line arguments like `-v` and `-F` -- you have to modify the `awk` or `perl` code directly to get the desired behavior.

Comment: @RichardHansen: Fair point, although in those examples the modification is pretty simple. `-f` would have been much more troublesome. However, it still might be a useful technique.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` flavor:

```
command | sed -ne '1p' -ne '/bla/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

### How to `grep` everything but the first line

The following will mostly get what you want, but it has several flaws (see the end of this post):

```sh
the command | (read l; echo $l; grep blah) | less
```

Instead, I recommend creating and using the following function:

```sh
grep1 () (
    IFS= read -r line
    printf %s\\n "${line}"
    grep "$@"
)
```

Here is how you would use it:

```sh
the command | grep1 blah | less
```

Example of it in action:

```
$ ps -ef | grep1 firefox
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
rhansen   3654  3311  4 13:33 ?        00:07:59 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
```

#### How it works

1. `read` consumes the first line of input from `command` and assigns it (unmodified) to the variable `line`
2. `printf` outputs the value of `line` (unmodified)
3. the remaining input lines are consumed, filtered, and output by `grep`

The first line never passes through `grep`, so there's no opportunity for it to filter it out.

#### Notes

- I enclosed the function body in `( ... )` instead of `{ ... }` because I don't want variable assignments inside the body to affect the caller's environment (the parentheses cause it to be run in a subshell, which isolates any changes from the caller).
- [`IFS=` prevents `read` from stripping leading and trailing whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6399568/712605)
- the `-r` argument to `read` prevents it from processing backslashes (the first line is perfectly preserved in the variable `line`)
- I use `printf %s\\n` instead of `echo` because `echo` might process backslashes, possibly causing the first line of output to be different from the original first line

#### Improvements

The above function has a minor problem:  If given empty input it will print a blank line.  The following avoids that problem:

```sh
grep1_better() (
    IFS= read -r line && printf %s\\n "${line}"
    grep "$@"
)
```

This works because `read` returns a non-zero return code if it encounters the end of input.  If there's no input, `read` will "fail" (return non-zero) and the `&&` will skip the `printf`.

But, now there's a new problem:  If there *is* input, but there aren't any newlines at all (for example, `printf %s foo`), the function will output nothing.  This is because `read` will encounter the end of input and "fail" even though there was some input.  Here's how that can be fixed:

```sh
grep1_even_better() (
    IFS= read -r line || [ -n "${line}" ] && printf %s\\n "${line}"
    grep "$@"
)
```

In English, the above says, "Read a line of input.  If the end of input wasn't encountered, or if something was read, then print what was read.  Then run `grep`."

A further improvement would be to detect when the function is being called with one or more filename arguments and react accordingly (read from the file(s) instead of standard input).

### What's wrong with this example?

The following code doesn't work:

```sh
the command | (read l; echo $l) | grep bla | less
```

There are two major problems:

- The first line is still piped through `grep`, so `grep` could still filter it out.
- The remaining lines of input are discarded by the second stage of the pipeline.  (More precisely, the "`the command`" command never gets an opportunity to output the remaining lines (modulo buffering) because nobody in the second stage is waiting to read them.)

In addition, there are a handful of minor problems:

- Because `IFS` is not set to the empty string before calling `read`, `read` will strip the first line's leading and trailing whitespace before assigning the variable `l`.
- Because `-r` is not passed to `read`, `read` will attempt to interpret backslashes in the first input line.  This could corrupt the first line.
- Because the argument to `echo` is not enclosed in double quotes, tabs and multiple consecutive whitespace will be converted to a single space.  If the first line contains column headings, this will break the alignment with the following rows.
- Because `echo` might process backslashes in its arguments, the first line may be corrupted.
- If the first line begins with `-`, `echo` might interpret the string as an option, not something to be printed.
- It'll print a blank line if given empty input.

These minor problems are also present in `the command | (read l; echo $l; grep blah) | less`, which is why I recommended the `grep1()` function.

Answer (score 0):

The `awk` and `sed` answers above are usually the way to go. Sometimes when the regex in question is complex and `grep` is the only option, the following `tee`-based option should work. Here `tee` writes its input to two "files", where `grep` and `head` consume the input via process substitution. `tee` also writes its input to standard output, which in this case needs to be redirected to `/dev/null`. The `sleep` is needed to ensure `head` returns its output before `grep`

```
command | tee  >(sleep 1; grep regex) >(head -1) >/dev/null
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what regex would be too complex for awk? awk recognizes all POSIX extended regexes (i.e. the same as `egrep`)

Comment: @rici, GNU `grep` with `-P` supports PCRE goodies such as look-ahead assertions, do not believe `awk` does this

Comment: OK, fair enough. Added a perl example.