# Bash language randomize order of words in .txt file

Tags: string, bash, shell, random, robots.txt

how do I randomize the order of words in a .txt file? I don't know any bash and don't know any good resources
thanks to all

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I randomize the lines in a file using a standard tools on Redhat Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886237/how-can-i-randomize-the-lines-in-a-file-using-a-standard-tools-on-redhat-linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's one word per line, you can use `shuf yourfile` to output them in random order, or

```
shuf yourfile > tmpfile && mv tmpfile yourfile
```

to write the shuffled contents back into `yourfile`.

Comment: You can use `tr ' ' '\n' < yourfile | shuf | tr '\n' ' '` to shuffle words in a file and put all the shuffled words on one line.

Answer (score 1):

If there is more than one word per line, you can use this Perl one-liner:

```
 perl -MList::Util -e '$/=""; print join " ", List::Util::shuffle split /\s/, <>' <in.txt >out.txt
```

If you don't like that output file will be in single line, you can change it be one word per line: simply replace `join " "` with `join "\n"`.

Comment: is there any way to shuffle words in each line?(line by line)