# Shuf - To Shuffle the contents of a file in linux

Tags: linux, tcsh

I am using some tcsh code that uses a command called shuf:

```
shuf $file_name > out.txt
```

http://tuxthink.blogspot.ca/2012/06/shuf-to-shuffle-contents-of-file.html

but seems my linux/bash version does not have it.  Does anyone knows a way to install it?

My linux/tcsh is:

```
$ echo $version
tcsh 6.14.00 (Astron) 2005-03-25 (x86_64-unknown-linux) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,sm,rh,color,filec
$ uname -mrs
Linux 2.6.18-194.8.1.el5 x86_64
```

Also, I am a user of the server but I do not have super user permission, can only perform local installations in my user folder.

Thanks!

Comment: Your linux/bash? You say and the output agrees that you use `tcsh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try your package manager or `sudo apt-get install shuf`

Comment: thanks a lot!  the problem is that I am not a super user, any other way for regular users?

Comment: The obvious is apply to the administrator of the system or write your own, a few lines of python should do the job.

Comment: i think u r right, that's easier.  thanks.

Comment: I found this temp solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886237/how-can-i-randomize-the-lines-in-a-file-using-a-standard-tools-on-redhat-linux