# Shuffling lines of a file with a fixed seed?

Tags: bash, sorting, shuffle, random-seed

I want to shuffle the lines of a file with a fixed seed so that I always get the same random order. The command I am using is as follows:

```
sort -R file.txt | head -200 > file.sff
```

What change could I make it so that it sorts with a fixed random seed?

Comment: doesn't `--random-source` work?

Comment: Just found the answer to this one myself, but yes it is with --random-source roe, kudos to you.

Comment: The answer is in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537191/the-sort-r-command-doesnt-sort-lines-randomly-in-linux

Answer (score 27):

The GNU implementation of `sort` has a `--random-source` argument. Passing this argument with the name of a file with known contents will result in a reliable set of output.

See the [Random sources](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Random-sources.html#Random-sources) documentation in the GNU coreutils manual, which contains the following sample implementation and example:

> ```
> get_seeded_random()
> {
>   seed="$1"
>   openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -pass pass:"$seed" -nosalt \
>     </dev/zero 2>/dev/null
> }
>
> shuf -i1-100 --random-source=<(get_seeded_random 42)
> ```

Since GNU `sort` is also part of coreutils, the relevant documentation applies there as well:

```
sort --random-source=<(get_seeded_random 42) -R file.txt | head -200 > file.sff
```

Comment: Since `sort` and `shuf` are both part of GNU coreutils, does it matter in the slightest? If one has one, they'll have both.

Comment: If using HomeBrew on macOS, `shuf` is `gshuf` (part of `coreutils` package).

Comment: `--random-source` is a good start, but note that it needs a larger number of bytes; otherwuse an `end of file ` error is thrown; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/60266215/1506477

Comment: @ThammeGowda, I'm having trouble seeing the difference from how the accepted answer to that question is advising folks to use `openssl enc` to generate a random stream and how this answer advises one to do so.

Answer (score 10):

Linux's [`shuf`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/shuf) command can take a file as a fixed source of randomness using the parameter `--random-source`:

```
shuf --random-source=some_file.txt file.txt | head -n200 > file.sff
```

If you don't want to bother with giving a full file, you can pipe one on the go:

```
shuf --random-source=<(yes 42) file.txt | head -n200 > file.sff
```

Comment: Edited random source to be infinite source to make sure `shuf` never runs out of bytes!

Comment: I tried to test this method by extracting 500 lines from a file of ascending order of 1 - 1000000, one number per line, and the distribution was highly uneven. (Histogram: https://pasteboard.co/E8dNcTzO19Yt.png) Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You may not need to use external tools like `sort`, whose options and usage may vary depending on your operating system. Bash has an internal random number generator accessible through the `$RANDOM` variable. It's common practice to seed the generator by setting the variable, like so:

```
RANDOM=$$
```

or

```
RANDOM=$(date '+%s')
```

etc. But of course, you can also use a predictable seed in order to get predictable not-so-random results:

```
$ RANDOM=12345; echo $RANDOM
28207
$ RANDOM=12345; echo $RANDOM
28207
```

To reorder the lines of the mapped file randomly, you can read the file into an array using mapfile:

```
$ mapfile -t a < source.txt
```

Then simply rewrite the array indices:

```
$ for i in ${!a[@]}; do a[$((RANDOM+${#a[@]}))]="${a[$i]}"; unset a[$i]; done
```

When reading a non-associative array, bash naturally orders elements in ascending order of index value.

Note that the *new* index for each line has the number of array elements added to it to avoid collisions within that range. This solution is still fallible -- there's no guarantee that `$RANDOM` will produce unique numbers. You can mitigate that risk with extra code that checks for prior use of each index, or reduce the risk with bit-shifting:

```
... a[$(( (RANDOM<<15)+RANDOM+${#a[@]} ))]= ...
```

This makes your index values into a 30-bit unsigned int instead of a 15 bit unsigned int.

Answer (score -6):

If you're randomly shuffling lines, you're not sorting. I haven't seen a `sort` with `--random-source` prompt before. It'd be interesting if it does exist. However, that's not sorting the lines in a fixed order.

I believe you'll have to write a program to that, and I don't think Bash can quite do it.

Actually, it might. The $RANDOM environment variable selects a random number from 0 to 32767. You can assign a seed to `RANDOM` and the random number sequence will appear over and over. You can use a [card dealing algorithm](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html). Read in each line into a Bash array, then use the card dealing algorithm to pick each line.

I'm not going to write a test program -- especially in Bash, but you should get the idea.